# Can I edit an application that is live on Heroku?

Tags: github, heroku

I have a Spring Web Application live on Heroku and it is deployed via my Github. I want to make a few edits to the application. If I edit the code in Eclipse and commit it to the connected Github repository with the Heroku account will the live Spring Application automatically update and display the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I edit the code in Eclipse and commit it to the connected Github repository with the Heroku account will the live Spring Application automatically update and display the changes?

Not by default, but if you [connect your GitHub and Heroku accounts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#enabling-github-integration) you can [enable automatic deploys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#automatic-deploys):

> When you enable automatic deploys for a GitHub branch, Heroku builds and deploys all pushes to that branch. If, for example, you have a development app on Heroku, you can configure pushes to your GitHub `development` branch to be automatically built and deployed to that app.
>
> [image]

I should also point out that you probably aren't "committing to a GitHub repository".

Since Git is a distributed version control system you're committing locally and then pushing those commits to GitHub. Heroku's deploy-from-GitHub is triggered by the push (and may be dependent on CI passing).